# QPrinter linker not able to find file

Tags: c++, qt, printing, linker

When I try to declare QPrinter anywhere in my code I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)      
public: virtual __thiscall QPrinter::~QPrinter(void)" (__imp_??1QPrinter@@UAE@XZ) 
referenced in function "private: void __thiscall ezXpns::on_loginButton_clicked(void)" (?
on_loginButton_clicked@ezXpns@@AAEXXZ)  
(path)\TestBuild_April3\TestBuild\ezxpns.obj    TestBuild

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) 
public: __thiscall QPrinter::QPrinter(enum QPrinter::PrinterMode)" (__imp_??
0QPrinter@@QAE@W4PrinterMode@0@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall 
ezXpns::on_loginButton_clicked(void)" (?on_loginButton_clicked@ezXpns@@AAEXXZ)  
(path)\TestBuild_April3\TestBuild\ezxpns.obj    TestBuild
```

After searching I found it implies, that linker can find method declaration, but not method itself. Also, it appears to fail at any mention of `QPrinter` . I thought that might be because this method is depreciated in QT5, but it appears new method of QT-printer communication was not yet released. What could be the problem? `#IFDEF` preprocessor declarations in QPrinter files?

My includes:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_ezxpns.h"
#include "Vector2D.h"
#include <QtPrintSupport\qprinter.h>
#include <QtPrintSupport\qprintdialog.h>
#include <QtPrintSupport\qtprintsupportglobal.h>
#include <qapplication.h>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you didn't enable QtPrintSupport for your project.
You can enable it by adding

```
QT += printsupport
```

to your .pro file.

For more information, [read here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtprintsupport/qtprintsupport-module.html).

Comment: I use visual studio, there is no .pro file. Creating pro file from qt menu, and adding this line to it doesn't seem to help. Should I change vcxproj file?

Comment: Okay, found how to do this. Right click on your project, QTproject settings, allow PrintSupport.